# Loop values one by one

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new in Xamarin. I am trying to create my first sample app that will be used loop values one by one. Each button click should print next value. So the first click, should print: 1, second: 2 and so one. How can i do it? Currently i've got only the last value: 9.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, i.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
Class Yourclass : Activity{
 int i = 0;
 yourButtonClickEvent(){
   i++;
   Toast.MakeText(this, i.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
 }}
```

**Update**:
I have made a counter variable named i, each time the button is pressed I increase the variable count. So that in your toast you can get the button pressed count and access that required data.

Comment: Please be sure to include an explanation instead of just answering with a block of code. Can you edit your answer to provide that?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a counter variable to achieve this. Make the counter variable global. The counter will keep count for the number of times your button was clicked. Based on the count you can print the next value.